# Does anyone know of a reg expression for uk date format

Tags: regex

Hi does any one know a reg ex for a uk date format e.g. dd/mm/yyyy.

The dd or mm can be 1 character e.g. 1/1/2010 but the year must always be 4 characters.

Thanks in advance

Comment: @codaddict, regular expressions are language neutral for the most part.

Comment: Many programming languages have perfect functions to parse date in any format and take care of number of days within a month, leap years, etc.

Answer (score 11):

```
^\d{1,2}/\d{1,2}/\d{4}$
```

will match 1/1/2000, 07/05/1999, but also 99/77/8765.

So if you want to do some rudimentary plausibility checking, you need

```
^(0?[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])/(0?[1-9]|1[012])/\d{4}$
```

This will still match 31/02/9999, so if you want to catch those, it's getting hairier:

```
^(?:(?:[12][0-9]|0?[1-9])/0?2|(?:30|[12][0-9]|0?[1-9])/(?:0?[469]|11)|(?:3[01]|[12][0-9]|0?[1-9])/(?:0?[13578]|1[02]))/\d{4}$
```

But this still won't catch leap years. So, modifying [a beast of a regex from regexlib.com](http://www.regexlib.com/REDetails.aspx?regexp_id=166):

```
^(?:(?:(?:(?:31\/(?:0?[13578]|1[02]))|(?:(?:29|30)\/(?:0?[13-9]|1[0-2])))\/(?:1[6-9]|[2-9]\d)\d{2})|(?:29\/0?2\/(?:(?:(1[6-9]|[2-9]\d)(?:0[48]|[2468][048]|[13579][26])|(?:(?:16|[2468][048]|[3579][26])00))))|(?:0?[1-9]|1\d|2[0-8])\/(?:(?:0?[1-9])|(?:1[0-2]))\/(?:(?:1[6-9]|[2-9]\d)\d{2}))$
```

will match

```
1/1/2001
31/5/2010
29/02/2000
29/2/2400
23/5/1671
01/1/9000
```

and fail

```
31/2/2000
31/6/1800
12/12/90
29/2/2100
33/3/3333
```

All in all, regular expressions may be able to match dates; validating them is not their forte, but if they are all you can use, it's certainly possible. But looks horrifying :)

Comment: It's usually better, once you've found a likely match, to stuff it into a variable of type date (on whatever the platform), and let the platform worry about leap year rules, etc.

Comment: The first 0 isn't optional, suffix it with a `?`

Comment: Either keep it simple, or search the web for an expression that handles everything including leap years. There isn't really any point to make a more complicated expression if it still can't handle all cases.

Comment: @Andrew Dunn: Thanks, I had missed that and have corrected it.

Comment: @Guffa: You're right, and I was - just took a while to change the monster regex to his exact specifications...

Answer (score 4):

Regex is not the right tool for this job.

It is very difficult (but possible) to come up with the regex to match a **valid** date. Things like ensuring Feb has `29` days on leap year and stuff is not easily doable in regex.

Instead check if your language library provides any function for validating dates.

PHP has one such function called [checkdate](http://php.net/manual/en/function.checkdate.php) :

```
bool checkdate  ( int $month  , int $day  , int $year)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
\b(0?[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])[/](0?[1-9]|1[012])[/](19|20)?[0-9]{2}\b
```

Match :

- 1/1/2010
- 01/01/2010

But also invalid dates such as February 31st

Comment: I think matching correct days in a month is useless when not matching february and leap years ;) Besides that, it is a difference between matching the form and matching the values.

Answer (score 0):

`^\d{1,2}/\d{1,2}/\d{4}$`

In braces there is min and max char count. `\d` means digit, `^` start, and `$` end of string.

Answer (score 0):

```
\b(0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])[- /.](0[1-9]|1[012])[- /.](19|20)\d\d
```

This wont validate the date, but you can check for format

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the similar requirements. 
Here is the complete regular expression along with Leap Year validation. 
Format: dd/MM/yyyy

(3[01]|[12]\d|0[1-9])/(0[13578]|10|12)/((?!0000)\d{4})|(30|[12]\d|0[1-9])/(0[469]|11)/((?!0000)\d{4})|(2[0-8]|[01]\d|0[1-9])/(02)/((?!0000)\d{4})|
29/(02)/(1600|2000|2400|2800|00)|29/(02)/(\d\d)(0[48]|[2468][048]|[13579][26])

It can be easily modified to US format or other EU formats.

**edited:**

(3[01]|[12]\d|0[1-9])/(0[13578]|10|12)/((?!0000)\d{4})|(30|[12]\d|0[1-9])/(0[469]|11)/((?!0000)\d{4})|(2[0-8]|[01]\d|0[1-9])/(02)/((?!0000)\d{4})|29/(02)/(1600|2000|2400|2800|00)|29/(02)/(\d\d)(0[48]|[2468][048]|[13579][26])

Comment: fails for 29/02/2000.  the century years 1600 and 2000 are leap years, but the century years 1700, 1800, and 1900 are not

Comment: fixed it - remove the space before the 29. I've edited the original.

Answer (score 0):

There are two things you want to do, which in my view are best considered separately

1) You want to make sure that the date is a real, actual date. 
For example the 2019-02-29 isn't a real date whereas 2020-02-29 is a real date because 2020 is a leap year

2) You want to check that the date is in the correct format (so dd/mm/yyyy)

The second point can be done easily enough with a simple RegEx, plenty of examples of that.

To complicate matters, if you ask Firefox if 2019-02-29 is a real date, it'll return NaN, which is what you'd expect.

Chrome, on the other hand will say it is a real date and give you back the 1st of March 2019 - which will validate

Chrome, will also accept a single digit number as a proper date too for some strange reason, feed it "2" and it'll give you full date from 2001 back - which will validate

So first step is to create a function which attempts to decipher a date (no matter the format) and works cross-browser to return a boolean indicating if the date is valid or not

```
function validatableDate(value) 
{
    Date.prototype.isValid = function() 
    {   // An invalid date object returns NaN for getTime() and NaN is the only
        // object not strictly equal to itself.
        return this.getTime() === this.getTime();
    };
    minTwoDigits = function(n) 
    {   //pads any digit less than 10 with a leading 0
        return (parseInt(n) < 10 ? '0' : '') + parseInt(n);
    }
    var valid_date = false;
    var iso_array = null;
    // check if there are date dividers (gets around chrome allowing single digit numbers)
    if ((value.indexOf('/') != -1) || (value.indexOf('-') != -1)) { //if we're dealing with - dividers we'll do some pre-processing and swap them out for /
        if (value.indexOf('-') != -1) {
            dash_parts = value.split('-');
            value = dash_parts.join("/");
            //if we have a leading year, we'll put it at the end and work things out from there
            if (dash_parts[0].length > 2) {
                value = dash_parts[1] + '/' + dash_parts[2] + '/' + dash_parts[0];
            }
        }

        parts = value.split('/');
        if (parts[0] > 12) { //convert to ISO from UK dd/mm/yyyy format
            iso_array = [parts[2], minTwoDigits(parts[1]), minTwoDigits(parts[0])]
        } else if (parts[1] > 12) { //convert to ISO from American mm/dd/yyyy format                                                
            iso_array = [parts[2], minTwoDigits(parts[0]), minTwoDigits(parts[1])]
        } else //if a date is valid in either UK or US (e.g. 12/12/2017 , 10/10/2017) then we don't particularly care what format it is in - it's valid regardless
        {
            iso_array = [parts[2], minTwoDigits(parts[0]), minTwoDigits(parts[1])]
        }

        if (Array.isArray(iso_array)) {
            value = iso_array.join("-");
            var d = new Date(value + 'T00:00:01Z');
            if (d.isValid()) //test if it is a valid date (there are issues with this in Chrome with Feb)
            {
                valid_date = true;
            }
            //if the month is Feb we need to do another step to cope with Chrome peculiarities
            if (parseInt(iso_array[1]) == 2) {
                month_info = new Date(iso_array[0], iso_array[1], 0);
                //if the day inputed is larger than the last day of the February in that year
                if (iso_array[2] > month_info.getDate()) {
                    valid_date = false;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return valid_date;
}
```

That can be compressed down to

```
function validatableDate(t) {
    Date.prototype.isValid = function () {
        return this.getTime() === this.getTime()
    }, minTwoDigits = function (t) {
        return (parseInt(t) < 10 ? "0" : "") + parseInt(t)
    };
    var a = !1,
        i = null;
    return -1 == t.indexOf("/") && -1 == t.indexOf("-") || (-1 != t.indexOf("-") && (dash_parts = t.split("-"), t = dash_parts.join("/"), dash_parts[0].length > 2 && (t = dash_parts[1] + "/" + dash_parts[2] + "/" + dash_parts[0])), parts = t.split("/"), i = parts[0] > 12 ? [parts[2], minTwoDigits(parts[1]), minTwoDigits(parts[0])] : (parts[1], [parts[2], minTwoDigits(parts[0]), minTwoDigits(parts[1])]), Array.isArray(i) && (t = i.join("-"), new Date(t + "T00:00:01Z").isValid() && (a = !0), 2 == parseInt(i[1]) && (month_info = new Date(i[0], i[1], 0), i[2] > month_info.getDate() && (a = !1)))), a
}
```

That gets you a cross-browser test as to whether the date can be validated or not and it'll read & decipher dates in formats

- yyyy-mm-dd
- dd-mm-yyyy
- mm-dd-yyyy
- dd/mm/yyyy
- mm/dd/yyyy

Once you've validated the date is a real, proper one you can then test the format with a regex. So for UK dd/mm/yy

```
function dateUK(value) {
    valid_uk_date=false;
    valid_date=validatableDate(value);
    if(valid_date && value.match(/^(0?[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])[\/](0?[1-9]|1[012])[\/]\d{4}$/))
    {   valid_uk_date=true;
    }
    return  valid_uk_date;              
}
```

You then know that the date is a real one and that it's in the correct format.

For yyyy-mm-dd format, you'd do:

```
function dateISO(value) {
    valid_iso_date=false;
    valid_date=validatableDate(value);
    if(valid_date && value.match(/^\d{4}[\/\-]\d{1,2}[\/\-]\d{1,2}$/))
    {   valid_iso_date=true;
    }
    return  valid_iso_date;             
}
```

It depends how thorough you want to be of course, for a rough check of format sanity a RegEx may be enough for your purposes. If however you want to test if the date is a real one AND if the format is valid then this will hopefully help point you along the way

Thanks